# Nullpointer when deserializing json to a list

Tags: c#, .net, json, .net-core-3.0

I'm trying to deserialize a JSON to a list of ReportVersandLogDtos with `System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer`

```
var reportVersandLogsAsync = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<ReportVersandLogDto>>(content, new JsonSerializerOptions {
                    PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
                    IgnoreNullValues = true
                });
```

Content looks like this:

```
[
  {
    "AnzahlArtikel": 6,
    "Betreff": "Cupra Daily News",
    "ReportId": 379717,
    "ReportVersandLogId": 4244138,
    "VersendetAm": "2019-11-02T06:30:15.997",
    "Link": "foo"
  }
]
```

The ReportVersandLogDto looks like this:

```
[JsonObject]
public class ReportVersandLogDto : IResource
{
    [JsonProperty("anzahlArtikel")]
    public long AnzahlArtikel { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("betreff")]
    public string? Betreff { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("hasBeenRead")]
    public bool HasBeenRead { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("reportId")]
    public long ReportId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("reportVersandLogId")]
    public long ReportVersandLogId { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("versendetAm")]
    public string? VersendetAm { get; set; }

    //[JsonProperty("link")]
    //public string? Link { get; set; }
}
```

Unfortunately, I get a NullPointerException when calling the `JsonSerializer.Deserialize` method.

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong... can you please point me in the right direction?

---

### Minimal reproducable example:

(It's a .net core 3.0 console app)
I've already posted the whole ReportVersandLogDto above (it uses attributes from Newtonsoft.Json)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var content = "\"[{\\\"AnzahlArtikel\\\":6,\\\"Betreff\\\":\\\"Cupra Daily News\\\",\\\"ReportId\\\":379717,\\\"ReportVersandLogId\\\":4244138,\\\"VersendetAm\\\":\\\"2019-11-02T06:30:15.997\\\",\\\"Link\\\":\\\"foo\\\"}]\"";
        var reportVersandLogsAsync = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<ReportVersandLogDto>>(content, new JsonSerializerOptions {
                PropertyNameCaseInsensitive = true,
                IgnoreNullValues = true
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Please provide [mcve] that we can copy and paste into console app.

Comment: `JsonSerializer.Deserialize()` does not throw a NullReferenceException. Create a [mre].

Comment: Not valid JSON. https://dotnetfiddle.net/ZkNwnS https://jsonlint.com/

Comment: Have you tried https://dotnetfiddle.net/XHZnD2 instead?

Comment: In your example, you have made your JSON a JSON string. You have too many quotes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you're mixing `Newtonsoft.Json` and `System.Text.Json`.

[`JsonProperty`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/JsonPropertyName.htm) is used in Newtonsoft.

[`JsonPropertyName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonpropertynameattribute?view=netcore-3.0) is the equivalent in `System.Text.Json`.

These attributes are not interchangeable between `Newtonsoft.Json` and `System.Text.Json`.  Try updating your class to the below:

```
public class ReportVersandLogDto
{
    [JsonPropertyName("anzahlArtikel")]
    public long AnzahlArtikel { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("betreff")]
    public string Betreff { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("hasBeenRead")]
    public bool HasBeenRead { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("reportId")]
    public long ReportId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("reportVersandLogId")]
    public long ReportVersandLogId { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("versendetAm")]
    public string VersendetAm { get; set; }

    [JsonPropertyName("link")]
    public string Link { get; set; }
}
```

Also, there's no need to declare the strings as nullable reference (`string?`) types unless you're using them in a nullable context.

Please see this [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/9NSi4a).